# Implementing OSDP encryption problems

Tags: encryption

I'm having trouble implementing the encryption part of the OSDP protocol on an Arduino.
http://www.siaonline.org/SiteAssets/SIAStore/Standards/OSDP_V2%201_5_2014.pdf

I've successfully done the negotiation part and have verified the RMAC-I response by decrypting the data and comparing with the plaintext. The part I'm stuck on is the encryption of the data packets. According to the spec, I use the RMAC-I response as my ICV for the aes128 CBC and I encrypt the packet using the S-MAC2 key.
My POLL packet (in hex) is as follows:
53 01 0e 00 0c 02 15 60
This gets padded
53 01 0e 00 0c 02 15 60 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
This gets xored with the ICV then encrypted with S-MAC2 as the key.
The first 4 bytes of the result is stored in the packet and sent
53 01 0e 00 0c 02 15 60 91 86 b9 3d 4a 29
Unfortunately the reader rejects the poll command with a NAK 06
I'm presuming my MAC values have not been computed correctly as I've compared my packet with the HID DTK tool (obviously the MAC and CRC values are the only difference). Can someone validate my process?

Answer (score 0):

Seems my process was correct but was let down by implementation (off by one error).

Answer (score 0):

2.1.7 is the current SIA spec.  IEC 60839-11-5 should be out soon. (the IEC standards version.)

The processing your describe is for the MAC suffix not the payload encryption.  MAC2 because it's only one block long (else you'd use MAC1 and then MAC2.)  OSDP uses AES to encrypt a throw-away copy of the entire message and then uses some bytes of the last cipherblock as the MAC that is transmitted.   OSDP encrypts the payload, if there is one.  In modern AES implementations you pass in an IV and a key and a buffer so one would not look at it as xoring the IV with the plaintext.